# MS Access Cannot filter by date range when using UNION Select query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS access database containing table for each country.

I've created a UNION Select query to join all of the tables in a database so I can filter out countries and dates and do calculations.

When I filter one date, the results are correct. But when I filter range of dates, I get incorrect results. It seems like date is wrongly formatted?

Here is the UNION Select query. I've tried it both with and without the Format function

```
SELECT "Argentina" as Country, Format([Argentina - Immediate Refund].[Date sent], "Short Date") As [Date sent], [Argentina - Immediate Refund].[Received date], [Argentina - Immediate Refund].[Released date], [Argentina - Immediate Refund].[Processed Forms] FROM [Argentina - Immediate Refund]

UNION ALL SELECT  "Austria" as Country, Format([Austria - Immediate Refund].[Date sent], "Short Date") As [Date sent], [Austria - Immediate Refund].[Received date], [Austria - Immediate Refund].[Released date], [Austria - Immediate Refund].[Processed Forms] FROM [Austria - Immediate Refund];
```

Here is screenshot of results when I filter dates from 1/10/2023 to 1/11/2023

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCwyR.png)

I've tried changing the date format in SQL statement

Comment: Never include spaces in your filed names, unless you're looking for trouble and you love typing brackets. Also double check for reserved qords, that will work sometimes...and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the formatting of date values:

```sql
SELECT 
    "Argentina" as Country, 
    [Date sent],
    [Received date], 
    [Released date], 
    [Processed Forms] 
FROM 
    [Argentina - Immediate Refund]

UNION ALL 

SELECT  
    "Austria" as Country, 
    [Date sent], 
    [Received date], 
    [Released date], 
    [Processed Forms] 
FROM 
    [Austria - Immediate Refund];
```

To convert text dates to true date values:

```sql
    "Argentina" as Country, 
    CVDate([Date sent]) As DateSent,
    CVDate([Received date]) As ReceivedDate, 
    CVDate([Released date]) As ReleasedDate, 
    [Processed Forms]
```

Comment: in my original query, I didn't have any formatting for the date values, so I already tried this.
I added the formatting just now to see if it will help, but it didn't change anything

Comment: Format returns text, thus you cannot sort those values. Your date fields _must_ of data type Date. Else use `CVDate` (which accepts _Null_ values) to convert as shown.

Comment: Agreed, but why using CVDate instead of CDAte ? You get a variant which is probably less efficient thatn a date. Ahhh perhpas for handling nulls ?

Comment: @iDevlop: Yes, for the possible _Null_ values.